# mongodb don't want to connect from my device

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I face this problem for 2 weeks now ,I was able to connect to my mongodb cluster before but now when i try to connect it give me this error message (queryTxt ETIMEOUT keep-connect-ebnzp.mongodb.net) ,I ask someone to try connect it from his pc and it connected and when i try to connect locally it work fine  so what is the problem

I use this url to connect

```
mongodb+srv://mohamed:<password>@keep-connect-ebnzp.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

mongodb config code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const db = process.env.MONGDB_URL;

const mongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    console.log('Mongo DB connected');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

image for error on my terminal
module.exports = mongoDB; [image]

Comment: Try connecting with terminal client using the same URI

Comment: what do you mean by terminal client ?

Comment: mongo shell, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/